# Fazer uma pesquisa entre duas datas no Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Tenho um programa onde eu preciso buscar através do GET no django os dados presentes entre duas datas (o usuário irá definir essas datas)

Models.py

```
class Data(models.Model):
    dev = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="data")
    voltage = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    current = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active_power = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reactive_power = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    temperature = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dev_energy = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    dev_on = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(max_length=70)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'data'
    verbose_name_plural = 'datas'

def __str__(self):
    return f'Datas'
```

Views.py

```
class DataViewSet(ModelViewSet):
#queryset = Data.objects.all()
queryset = Data.objects.filter(time__range=[data_inicio, data_final])
serializer_class = DataSerializer
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'data/$', views.Data.as_view(), name='data'),
url(r'data/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})-(?P<month>[0-9]{2})-(?P<day>[0-9]{2})/$',
    views.Data.as_view(), name='filter_data'),
```

]

Eu preciso ajustar as views de forma que os parâmetros data_inicio e data_final sejam passados pela url, porém só achei como passar apenas um dos parâmetros por ela. Isso é possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseado nos comentários e na edição do post:

De um modo geral, existem três formas de se passar dados para uma view:

1. No path da URL (ex.: https://www.seu_site.com.br/livros/10)
2. Como argumento na URL (ex.: https://www.seu_site.com.br/livros?identificador=10)
3. No body da requisição REST - Não será descrita nesta resposta

### Usando o path

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('livros/<int:identificador>/', views.livros, name='os_livros'),
]
```

`views.py`

```
def livros(request, identificador):
    # sua lógica aqui
```

### Usando como argumento

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('livros/', views.livros, name='os_livros'),
]
```

`views.py`

```
def livros(request):
    identificador = requests.GET.get('identificador')
    # sua lógica aqui
```

### Seu caso

No seu caso, eu usaria a segunda forma.

Algo como: https://www.seu_site.com.br/data?inicio=1/1/2021&fim=31/1/2021

Sua url seria: path('data/', views.sua_view, name='sua_view_name')

Em views.py você teria:

```
def sua_view(request):
    data_inicio = requests.GET.get('inicio')
    data_fim = requests.GET.get('fim')
    # sua lógica aqui
```

**Nota** Os valores são recebidos como string e devem ser convertidos para o formato desejado caso necessário

Espero que ajude

Answer (score -2):

Simples:

```
Data.objects.filter(time__range=(data_inicial, data_final))
```

Elegante:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    dev = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="data")
    voltage = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    current = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active_power = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reactive_power = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    temperature = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dev_energy = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    dev_on = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField(max_length=70)

    objects = DataManager()

    def __str__(self): 
        return f'Datas'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'data'
        verbose_name_plural = 'datas'
```

```
class DataManager(models.Manager):
    def entre_datas(self, data_ini, data_fim):
        self.filter(time__range=(data_ini, data_fim))

Data.objects.entre_datas(<DATA_INICIAL_AQUI>, <DATA_FINAL_AQUI>)
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Data.objects.filter(time__range=(data_inicial, data_final)) eu coloco na view do data manager?

Comment: O DataManager faz parte do Model (models.py). Você está querendo fazer form, view e template para recuperação dos dados? Se sim, de uma olhada [aqui](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/questions/2017/03/17/getting-form-data-to-appear-in-url-and-for-use-in-the-next-view.html)

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria de fazer apenas o View, faz pouco tempo que mexo no django e ainda não mexi com form e template

Comment: Veja o link que passei, tem a `views.py` lá.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, eu ajustei o models conforme a forma "elegante", porém eu ainda não consegui arrumar o views mesmo com o link estou com dificuldades de aplicar ao meu exemplo

Comment: Sugiro colocar todos os arquivos importantes do seu projeto: urls.py, models.py, views.py em um novo post e explicar o que você quer exatamente.

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, poderia dizer o porque para que eu melhore a resposta? Acredito que minha resposta tenha atendido ao tópico "Fazer uma pesquisa entre duas datas no Django"

Comment: Editei e coloquei as views e as urls para dar uma ideia do que eu preciso

Comment: Respondido frente aos comentários em uma resposta diferente.